# Why won't "if this in thislist" return True when user inputs "this" and "thislist"?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm trying to understand how some code works so I've made my own simple code that *should* act like how the more complex code works. However, it seems that I'm missing something. I made a simple program to pass a "trigger" to compare to my list.

```
def function(findme, thislist):
  print("FindMe: {}".format(findme))
  print("In This List: {}".format(thislist))
  if findme in thislist:
    print("In!")
    return thislist

while(True):
  find = []
  list = []
  find.append(input("Input number to find: "))
  print("Find: {}".format(find))
  list.append(input("Input 1st number: "))
  list.append(input("Input 2nd number: "))
  print("List: {}".format(list))
  result = function(find, list)
  print(result)
  if result is not None:
    print("returned list")
    print(list)
  else:
    print("nothing returned")
```

The code finishes returning None and printing "nothing returned". I input 1 as find and 1, 2 as list. What am I missing here?

p.s. I'm new to python and stack overflow, forgive my messy post :x

Comment: You ask if the list `findme` is an element of the list `thislist`. Well, it isn't. The first and only entry of `findme` might be in the list `thislist`. Why is `findme` a list anyway?

Comment: BTW, you really shouldn't call your list `list` because you overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for your insight! I input 'findme' as a list because the code I'm trying to emulate passes what I believe is a tuple of data. 

Basically the function takes in data and checks if that data is within the passed threshold tuples (Set in code, not set by input). The code then returns if the data exceeds the thresholds. I'm basically trying to replicate that here but it seems I'm doing something a little different.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search if a list contains a `sublist` that way.

If you want to check if multiple elements are in the list, then you can do this instead

```py
if (all(x in thislist for x in findme)):
    print ("Sublist in the mainlist")
    return thislist
```

This is one way to do it, if you do not have to compare lists, then you could simply use the code which you have just replace `findme` with `findme[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the search value is a list itself. So you check if a list with one value is in the list with the values you want to find. It is not. The one value in the search list might be in the list with the values.

So you should use a single value as your search term.

I optimized the names of some variables, used f-strings for formatting and used fixed values for filling the list so you can test it faster.

```
def is_in_list(findme, data):
    print(f"FindMe: {findme}")
    print(f"In This List: {data}")
    if findme in data:
        print("In!")
        return True
    return False


find = input("Input number to find: ")
print(f"Find: {find}")
data = []
data.append("42")
data.append("23")
print(f"List: {data}")
if is_in_list(find, data):
    print(data)
else:
    print("nothing returned")
```

One more change. It doesn't make much sense to return the same list from the function that you put in there as a parameter. So I used return values of `True` and `False` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Originally I was just passing the list/findme back and forth to check on the console that the code was passing the values correctly. Aside from that, I believe I understand what you're saying; that I'm trying to find a list within a list and that's why it's not returning true. If this were to be passed a tuple/data (the example code reads: 'threshold_list = [(200, 255)]' ), would you mind explaining how would this change my program?